# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type With @Entity and @Repository Setup with Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have looked through all the other stackoverflows for this topic and none had the answer.  I am getting the "Not a managed type" on my Entity.  Here are the classes.

ENTITY:

```
package com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.jdo.annotations.Unique;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUST", schema = "SAMS")
public class CustDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3304734256617027874L;

    @Id
    @Unique(name = "IXCUS1")
    @Column(name = "CUST_ID")
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name = "CUST_CAN_CALL_IN")
    private String customerCanCallIn;

    @Column(name = "CUST_ADD_DT")
    private Integer customerAddDate;

    @Unique(name = "IXCUS2")
    @Column(name = "TXPYR_ID")
    private String taxPayerId;


}
```

REPO:

```
package com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.connector;

import com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface DB2CustConnector extends JpaRepository<CustDto, Integer> {

    @Query("select CUST_ID from SAMS.CUST where TXPYR_ID = ':taxPayerId'")
    List<CustDto> retrieveCustomerIdByTaxPayerId(@Param("taxPayerId") String taxPayerId);

}
```

APPLICATION:

```
package com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.*",
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.exception",
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.service",
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.*",
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.rest.*",
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.inbound.rest.*"
})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.connector"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
        "com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models"
})
public class BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

ADAPTOR:

```
package com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.adaptor;

import com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.connector.DB2CustConnector;
import com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class DB2Adaptor {

    private final DB2CustConnector db2CustConnector;

    public DB2Adaptor(
            DB2CustConnector db2CustConnector
    ) {
        this.db2CustConnector = db2CustConnector;
    }

    public List<CustDto> retrieveCustomerByTaxPayerId(String TaxPayerId) {
        return db2CustConnector.retrieveCustomerIdByTaxPayerId(TaxPayerId);
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\api\inbound\rest\controller\CustomerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'onboardingService' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\service\OnboardingService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2Adaptor' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\api\outbound\db2\adaptor\DB2Adaptor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2CustConnector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication.main(BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication.java:27) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'onboardingService' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\service\OnboardingService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2Adaptor' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\api\outbound\db2\adaptor\DB2Adaptor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2CustConnector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2Adaptor' defined in file [C:\code\java\workspace\brokerage-party-onboarding\application\build\classes\java\main\com\somecompany\brokerage\party\onborading\api\outbound\db2\adaptor\DB2Adaptor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2CustConnector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DB2CustConnector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.somecompany.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models.CustDto
  at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
  at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:161) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
  ... 58 common frames omitted
```

I can add any code if someone needs any others but I feel these are the big one.

Spring Boot 2.2.5

I have been searching and reading for hours and have not found an answer.

TRIED: Changing the sql to reflect the CustDto class info.  Still get the error.

```
@Repository
public interface DB2CustConnector extends JpaRepository<CustDto, Integer> {

    @Query("select c.customerId from CustDto c where c.taxPayerId = ':taxPayerId'")
    List<CustDto> retrieveCustomerIdByTaxPayerId(@Param("taxPayerId") String taxPayerId);

}
```

TRIED: Removing the annotation and the query to see if that is the isse.  Still get the error.

```
public interface DB2CustConnector extends JpaRepository<CustDto, Integer> {

}
```

NOTE: while debugging org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl in method managedType the jpaEntityTypeMap is empty.  Any thoughts on how I can make this have values since I alreayd use @Entity and @EntityScan?

Comment: Why do you have all these annotations on the Spring Boot class? You don't need them. Remove everything and just add @SpringBootApplication and try again

Comment: @SimonMartinelli if I remove the enable jpa then it says there is no bean when I inject it into a service class.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I stripped it down to just {at}SpringBootApplication {at}EnableJpaRepositories and it still gives me the not a managed type error.  It appears without the enable jpa repos that it will not make a bean with the {at}Repository annotation.

Comment: What are you injecting? The entity?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added the Adaptor class that is injecting this bean.  The adaptor is then used in the service to make the call to the DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for whatever reason stripping the application down to the following fixed my error.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BrokeragePartyOnboradingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: ATSpringBootApplication uses ATEnableAutoConfiguration already scans for ATEntity classes present in the base package. Unless the entities are defined separately outside you scan base package, you won't need the ATEntityScan. Just the ATSpringBootApplication would suffice. Now as to why in you case supplying both ATEntityScan and ATSpringBootApplication is causing the issue needs investigation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within the `@SpringBootApplication` , try to remove the `*` within the package name and try to write full packaged structure.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
   "com.schwab.brokerage.party.onborading.api.outbound.db2.models"
})
```

Also note that `@EntityScan` does not create beans. Only `@SpringBootApplication` will create beans, `@EntityScan` only identifies which classes should be used by a specific persistence context.

Try not to scan every package, as everything within the base package having main class , scan everything within the package , having `@Component` or any stereotype annotation.

Comment: Removed all the scan packages and it threw errors on other beans not being created.  I added this one above here and it still gives the same error.  It is like it does not see it has {at}Entity on it but it does.

Answer (score 0):

The Query looks like SQL query, you need to change it to JPQL query syntax.

```
select c.customerId from CustDto c where c.taxPayerId = :taxPayerId
```

Comment: I changed it to customerId and still get the same error about not a managed type.

Comment: Then maybe the error is about the configuration. Spring Boot remove this burden for you already, just remove all the annotations in main class with @SpringBootApplication and run again

Comment: If I remove the enable jpa line then it does not find a bean when I try to inject this into a service adaptor.  I can remove the scan packages on Spring Boot App.

Comment: which spring boot version that you are using?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.2.5

Comment: Hmm have you try remove the Repository annotations?

Comment: Which dbms you are using btw

Comment: I will try removing the @Repository notation.
dbms?  Do you mean like Hibernate or am I misunderstanding the ask?

Comment: i mean which database you are using?

Comment: Removing the @Repository didn't change anything.

Comment: I am calling DB2 database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the `jakarta.persistence` package instead of the `javax.Persistence` package.

Also note the following points:

1. For Spring boot version above 3.0.0 use `jakarta.persistence` package
2. `javax.persistance` works perfectly with any Spring Boot versions less than 3.0

[Here is a screenshot of the required import statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAPf.jpg)